# Temporarily add multiple ip addresses to interface in 22.04

Tags: networking, bash, 22.04, netplan, ip

I need to temporarily, *dynamically* add and remove ip addresses from the `netplan.conf` (`/etc/netplan/myNetplanConfig.conf`).

In earlier versions the `ip` command could be used to temporarily add ip addresses to an interface, but I can't seem to find a replacement for it in Ubuntu 22.04 and I can't find any information on it in [man netplan](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man5/netplan.5.html) or in the [netplan documentation](https://netplan.io/examples).

I've thought about generating the `netplan.conf` with bash, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution to this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Update the netplan configuration file
cat << EOF > /etc/netplan/myNetplanConf.yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    # 1st network interface
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.10/24]
  version: 2
EOF

# Apply the changes to the network configuration
sudo netplan apply
```

Using the current solution means, that the ip addresses are added *statically* (they will *live* beyond a single boot cycle) and the `netplan.conf` has to be applied each time an ip address is added or removed.

Another solution is to add ip addresses to the `netplan.conf` using the `sed` command.

```
# Search for the existing ip addresses (.10) in the interface eth0 and append the new ip addresses (.11 .12 ...) to the list.
sed -i '/eth0/,/^\s*$/{/\s*addresses:\s*\[.*192\.168\.1\.(10).*\]/{s//&, 192.168.1.11, 192.168.1.12/}}' /etc/netplan/myNetplanConf.conf

# Apply the changes to the network configuration
sudo netplan apply
```

... and remove them using the same method.

```
# Search for the ip addresses (.11 and .12) in the interface eth0 and delete the corresponding entries from the netplan.conf file.
sed -i '/eth0/,/^\s*$/{/\s*addresses:\s*\[.*192\.168\.1\.(11|12).*\]/d}' /etc/netplan/myNetplanConf.conf

# Apply the changes to the network configuration
sudo netplan apply
```

- Why does the `ip` command not work with `netplan`?
- Are there better solutions to add/remove ip addresses with `netplan`?
- ... or am I just completely off the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ip` command still exists in Ubuntu 22.04.  It is part of the `iproute2` package that is installed by default as part of `ubuntu-minimal`.

You do not need to push temporary changes to network state through `netplan`, which is after all a configuration tool.

Comment: I've been unable to use the `ip` command in Ubuntu 22.04 (commands are executed but ips aren't added). I haven't installed any additional libraries or anything that could interfere. Has anything changed since 20.04?

Comment: no, the `ip` command is still a standard part of the system and we've had no reports of it not succeeding in adding IP addresses to interfaces.  You might check the kernel logs (dmesg) to see if there's some kind of driver error on your hardware.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to dmesg. Somehow `ifconfig` just didn't show the added ip addresses. They did show up though when using `ip a`.

Answer (score 1):

changing the netplan yaml makes most sense, when working with netplan ...

there is a nice tool for yaml handling called `yq`.
at least adding an IP is simple.

```
yq e '.network.ethernets.enp2s0.addresses += ["11.11.11.11/24" ]' network.yaml > new.yaml
```

A removal looks like

```
yq e '.network.ethernets.enp2s0.addresses -= ["11.11.11.11/24" ]' network.yaml > new.yaml
```

a `netplan apply` must be done anyway.